# quicksort help, not sure why partitioning returns index and not array

Tags: partitioning, quicksort

i was wondering if anyone could help me on quicksort. i understand the general idea for partitioning, but not sure why it returns an index

```
int partition(int arr[], int left, int right)
{
      int i = left, j = right;
      int tmp;
      int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

      while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i] < pivot)
                  i++;
            while (arr[j] > pivot)
                  j--;
            if (i <= j) {
                  tmp = arr[i];
                  arr[i] = arr[j];
                  arr[j] = tmp;
                  i++;
                  j--;
            }
      }

      return i;
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
      int index = partition(arr, left, right);
      if (left < index - 1)
            quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
      if (index < right)
            quickSort(arr, index, right);
}
```

i understand the whole rearranging part. it makes sense to me, but im not sure why partition is returning just an index. i thought it was supposed to return an array? like if the problem was to ... Sort {1, 12, 5, 26, 7, 14, 3, 7, 2}. i thought it would return...

1, 2, 5, 7, 3, 14, 7, 26, 12

i guess thats why im not understanding the actual quicksort function. but if someone could help explain it clearly and in an easy to understand way, it would be much appreciated. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The index that has been returned is only there to identify the end of recurrsion within the QuickSort algorithm. It's mainly the index of the pivot element that is used to identify the smaller and bigger numbers.

AND: You are referring to an enhanced Quick Search Algorithm. In the basic version of the QuickSearch algorithm the returned index won't be needed.

It would also work with: (but a lot slower)

```
void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) 
{
      if (left < right)
      {
         int index = partition(arr, left, right);
         quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
         quickSort(arr, index+1, right);
      } 
}
```

Comment: By "a lot slower" do you mean it would take forever? It doesn't look like you're checking for the base case, so I think you will get infinite recursion.

Comment: Your implementation is wrong. I applied the partition method from the question and `quickSort` from your answer to an array = [0, 4, 0, 3, 3], and it wasn't sorted

Answer (score 1):

Your partition function is modifying the array in-place. The integer it is returning is the index before which values are smaller than the pivot, and starting at which the values are bigger than the pivot. The two recursive calls are sorting the smaller elements and the larger elements; the condition tested before the recursive calls serves as the base case.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. I'm still wondering though, how does the quickSort actually do the sorting? I understand the array is partitioned after calling partition, but what exactly are the left and right parameters? I guess I'm still not seeing how it is putting all the numbers in the correct place. Thanks a bunch = )

Comment: The left and right parameters indicate the left and right endpoints between which partition operates (the assumption being that what falls outside of these boundaries has been sorted, or will be sorted, by another recursive call). The actual sorting occurs when partition swaps elements (between left and right) which are incorrectly positionned with respect to the pivot.